# How can I simulate output impedance of EMI filter with LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, impedance, emi-filtering

I use Wurth EMI line filter spice module, but I can not simulate the same attenuation and frequency wave of specification. And how can I simulate the output impedance of filter?

I update the simulation picture as follows:
Wurth 810911001 website information:
Electrical parameter:
[image]
Common mode insertion loss:
[image]
Differential mode insertion loss
[image]

My LTspice result:
Schematic:
[image]
Common mode signal simulation
[image]
Differential mode signal simulation
[image]

Result: It seems that common signal close to the official website data. But different signal has some deviation. Is there anything wrong with my simulation?

Comment: Please provide important details. Not sure which filter you want to simulate. Please describe the problem you are experiencing, its not clear if you want to simulate common mode or differential mode attenuation, also provide the plot in LT spice with the dB axis shown instead of chopped off.

Comment: What model are you using, one from here? https://www.we-online.com/en/support/design-tools/libraries/ltspice

Comment: FYI, the filter should be embedded in a 50 ohm system: use two sources on the line side (Rser = 50), and set them in phase for CM or out of phase for DM. Likewise on the load side, two 50 ohm terminations (or sources to see emissions rather than susceptibility). Remember to set only an input or output source to active (AC 1), and zero everywhere else.

Comment: I used wurth filter 810911001 for simulation. and the model also downlown on wurth website.

Comment: I have update the information. Please help point out the problem